# content of file are not displaying in php

Tags: php

i am reading and displaying content of file.but there is nothing showing no error or warning  in php code.

here is my php code

```
<html>
<head><title>assignment 1</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$DOCUMENT_ROOT=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$filename=$DOCUMENT_ROOT."new/guestbook.txt";         //filename
$fp=fopen($filename,"r");
while(true) {           
$lineread=fgets($fp);                                //end of file
if(feof($fp)) {
break;
}
echo explode("|",$lineread);                       //for breaking content of file in parts using |.
}
fclose($fp);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is html code after executing php script

```
<html>
<head><title>assignment 1</title></head>
<body></body></html>
```

guestbook.txt file

shubham|shukla|phone|4566|rishikesh|16-07-01|na

Both answers here are not working.

Comment: You can't just echo the explode, the explode returns as an array not string

Comment: @MuthaFury i have tried both answers but they are not working

Comment: What do you get when you use print_r() provided by user3619389

Comment: @MuthaFury it does nothing.still the same,no error no display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo explode` is not possible because its an `array`. To `echo` an `array` use `print_r()`

Anyway, I dont think you wont just output the array, but output each line. For this, loop through the `explode array`.

Try it this way:

```
$lines = explode("|",$lineread);

foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    echo $line . '</br>';
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated your code and this must work.

```
<html>
<head><title>assignment 1</title></head>
<body>
<?php
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
$filename = $DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/new/guestbook.txt";
$fp = fopen( $filename, "r" );

$lineread = fgets( $fp );
$lines = explode( '|', $lineread );

foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    echo $line . '</br>';
}

fclose( $fp );
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not working. i have replaced echo explode("|",$lineread); with foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    echo $line . '</br>';
}

Comment: Allright, hold on. I will test it on my server and post the code i used after

Answer (score 0):

You can't use echo to output an array .

either store it in a var and use foreach loop to echo

or

$var = explode("|",$lineread);

use print_r($var);

will output the content as is.

Comment: its still not working using $var = explode("|",$lineread);

use print_r($var);